# how to resolve circular import involving haystack?

Tags: django, import, signals, django-haystack

## Haystack

[haystack_signal_processor](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#haystack-signal-processor) let you use custom signal processor to initiate index for certain models.

I have in my settings.py

`HAYSTACK_SIGNAL_PROCESSOR='my_app.signals.MySignalProcessor'`
(this imports `signals.py` so. this is settings -> signals)

then inside my `signals.py` I have
`from my_app.models import my_model` # to connect my_model
And my_app.models.py has `from django.conf import settings`
(signals -> models -> settings)

How do I resolve this circular import?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

taken from https://github.com/PitonFoundation/atlas/commit/cc0abcb

Instead of importing the model on top of your signals.py file, import the models in the methods of your custom SignalProcessor using get_model:

```
from django.db.models.loading import get_model

class MySignalProcessor(signals.BaseSignalProcessor):
    def setup(self):
        MyModel = get_model('myApp', 'MyModel')
        models.signals.post_save.connect(self.handle_save, sender=MyModel)
```